# Word documents with mutliple tables to excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Is there a macro or similar example that will take word documents with similar layout and table structures, pull the needed information and put it in a specific layout in excel? The tables are all the same structure with the exception of a few where the there might be more rows.

I'm not very familiar with excel or vba and my attempt at books and google hasn't found me anything yet.

Comment: yes, I can confirm, you can do it with VBA. But I can't provide any complete solution as this is rather individual problem, no unified solution is available. So, you need to search for Word-Excel interaction (search for [word-vba][excel-vba] at the same time here in SO), search for `Table object` for MS Word VBA and Ranges for MS Excel VBA.  These will be a good start...

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out with your comment, more keyword searches and a bunch of trial and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr Excel has a great example that helped me through it.

[Here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/36875-word-table-into-excel-worksheet.html#post2612771)